# I have to run a get-item or set-item command before I can have my winrm remote command work

Tags: python, winrm

I am trying to run a powershell script from my lambda function which is written by python3.7.

The command is quite simple.

```
import winrm
s = winrm.Session('10.251.3.22', auth=('jiayu', 'Securitypassword'))
result = s.run_ps("hostname")   // or similar command "result = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])"
print(result.std_out)
```

The third command always got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/jiayu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/**init**.py", line 39, in run_cmd
shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
File "/home/jiayu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
File "/home/jiayu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 265, in send_message
raise WinRMOperationTimeoutError()
winrm.exceptions.WinRMOperationTimeoutError

However, if I run either of the following command on the destination server(10.251.3.22), and rerun the above third command, it could finish successfully and print out the result correctly.

1. Get-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic
2. Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic -Value $true

I am not that good at winrm and windows authentication, does anyone happen to know the reason ?

[image: s.run_cmd command finished successfully after run set-item]

Comment: More precisely, I have to use the "Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic -Value $true" command to make my s.run_cmd command to work inside my pythen script.

Comment: Interest thing is when I pull our the value of the parameter, it always returns to "true".

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Service\Auth

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   Basic                                          true


PS C:\Windows\system32>